# How to interperet the 'num_layers' line when using Keras Tuner

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, keras-tuner

I'm reading an article about tuning hyperparameters in keras tuner. It includes code to build a model that has this code:

```
def build_model(hp):
    """
    Builds model and sets up hyperparameter space to search.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    hp : HyperParameter object
        Configures hyperparameters to tune.
        
    Returns
    -------
    model : keras model
        Compiled model with hyperparameters to tune.
    """
    # Initialize sequential API and start building model.
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
    
    # Tune the number of hidden layers and units in each.
    # Number of hidden layers: 1 - 5
    # Number of Units: 32 - 512 with stepsize of 32
    for i in range(1, hp.Int("num_layers", 2, 6)):
        model.add(
            keras.layers.Dense(
                units=hp.Int("units_" + str(i), min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32),
                activation="relu")
            )
        
        # Tune dropout layer with values from 0 - 0.3 with stepsize of 0.1.
        model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(hp.Float("dropout_" + str(i), 0, 0.3, step=0.1)))
    
    # Add output layer.
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation="softmax"))
    
    # Tune learning rate for Adam optimizer with values from 0.01, 0.001, or 0.0001
    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice("learning_rate", values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
    
    # Define optimizer, loss, and metrics
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
                  loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  metrics=["accuracy"])
    
    return model
```

I'm confused about what the numbers, 1,2 and 6 mean in the range function for the `num_layers` line.

Comment: so the number of hidden layers is not 1-5, it is 2-6?

Comment: It is between 1 and 6 but only the the values starting from 2 to 6 are tunable. And 6 is part of the python range so you can only expect values from 1 to 5.

Comment: How can I define the input layer without flatening the features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the [docs](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/hyperparameters/#int-method), the 2 and 6 are referring to the min and max values respectively. Also note:

> [...] max_value is included in the possible values this parameter can take on

So this line:

```
for i in range(1, hp.Int("num_layers", 2, 6)):
```

basically means: generate a `x` number of `Dense` layers, where `x` is between 1 and 5 and the range from 2 to 6 is the hyperparameter you are working on / tuning.

Comment: do you mean ```x``` is between 1 and 5 and therefore the range is from 2 to 6? so for example if i wanted the number of hidden layers to be between 5 and ten the line would be:

```for i in range(5, hp.Int("num_layers", 6, 11)):```

Comment: okay I understand now, thankyou. So if I want at least 5 layers and at most 10 layers, all of which are tunable it is ```for i in range(5, hp.Int("num_layers", 5, 10)):```

Comment: @YosephIsmail No problem. See my other comment and updated answer.